# How do I merge back into remote branch

Tags: git, github

I have these 2 branches on my remote GitHub repository:

- **development**
- **master**

How do I merge development into master on the remote repository? I've tried

```
git merge development
```

and

```
git merge origin
```

but it says the repo is up to date so I'm doing it wrong because github says development is 12 commits ahead of master.

**Update**

Thanks for the follow ups - here's some more info, I did a push to the remote repository with

```
git push origin
```

and my changes have been committed. If I do a clone in another folder I see all the changes there if I checkout the development branch.

```
git branch -av 
development      8265e30 - etc
hotfix-t4        8342e44 - etc 
*master          0041bod - Initial Commit
  remotes/origin/HEAD  -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/development 8265e30 - etc
  remotes/origin/experimental 22cd3ef test1
  remotes/origin/hotfix-t4 8342e44 test
  remotes/origin/master 0041bod Initial commit
```

Comment: What does `git branch -av` give you?

Comment: After commit, you need to push to changes to respective branch. Check out following links

http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/

http://help.github.com/remotes/

http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: What version of git are you using (`git --version`) and do you have the config option `push.default` set (`git config push.default`)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The behaviour of `git push` or `git push origin` (i.e. when you don't also specify a refspec as the last parameter) is rather surprising - by default it pushes each branch to one of the same name so long as a branch with that name exists both locally and remotely.  (This default can be changed with the `push.default` config option.)

So, to be sure that you have correctly pushed a particular branch to the same name in the remote `origin`, it's a good idea to always use this form:

```
git push origin <branch-name>
```

... which is equivalent to `git push origin <branch-name>:<branch-name>`.

So, in full, to make sure that you have merged `development` to `master` locally, and then pushed `master` to GitHub, do exactly the following:

```
git checkout master
git merge development
git push origin master
```